# is buffered reader thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader

Is there any way i can get a thread safe buffered reader .I got the the following info when i ran this code#

```
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=de.factfinder.resource.Resource@1b7aeb4
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStream@3d6fb9
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStreamReader@171e0f6
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=java.io.BufferedReader@1684179
28 started Reading
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=de.factfinder.resource.Resource@1b7aeb4
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStream@3d6fb9
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStreamReader@171e0f6
Threadid=28 ObjectReference=java.io.BufferedReader@1684179
28 finished Reading
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=de.factfinder.resource.Resource@1bebf14
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStream@3d6fb9
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStreamReader@171e0f6
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=java.io.BufferedReader@1684179
38 started Reading
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=de.factfinder.resource.Resource@1bebf14
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStream@3d6fb9
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=java.io.InputStreamReader@171e0f6
Threadid=38 ObjectReference=java.io.BufferedReader@1684179
38 finished Reading
```

The hash codes for buffered reader , InputStreamReader and InputStream remains same.Why?

Comment: Kind-of skimmed over the details, but can't you just create a thread-safe wrapper class?

Comment: I think the hashcode for a BufferedReader might be identical if the InputStream is identical. Also could you try to explain the situation a little bit better? It's hard to formulate a fitting answer.

Comment: Are `reader` etc. static or are those local variables? How do you create that output? The hash code should change for every new object and AFAIK using a constructor there's no way an already exisiting object might be created (unless that happend in some native code but I doubt that's the case for `BufferedReader` etc.).

Comment: There seem to be two questions here... What do the hash code and thread-safety have to do with one another?

Comment: If this is a local variable, could you post the code that calls this method as well as the code that produces the output you posted?

Comment: Can you post your actual code as this doesn't compile?

Comment: readLine from BufferedReader should be thread safe (from current source). Could you show some code and also describe why you want multiple threads using the same BufferedReader?

Answer (score 5):

> Is `BufferedReader` thread safe?

The javadoc doesn't state the a BufferedReader is thread-safe, but when I look at the source code I see that the read methods use `synchronize` and an internal `lock` object.  (You can check this for yourself at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html)

So the answer is (probably) yes, though it *may* depend on the implementation and version of Java that you are using.

However, there are two other things to take into account:

- A `BufferedReader` is a wrapper for a `Reader`, which is typically a wrapper for other classes.  If parts of the same "I/O stack" are used by other threads, the fact that `BufferedReader` is thread-safe is not sufficient.
- If you have two threads both trying to read from the same `BufferedReader` you can get into trouble due to the threads not coordinating.  While the individual read operations behave atomically, sequences of operations do not.

In short, thread-safety is not necessarily sufficient to ensure that there won't be problems in a multi-threaded application.

> The hash codes for `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader` and `InputStream` remains same.  Why?

The probability of 3 new objects having the same identity hashcodes as 3 previously created objects is very small, so I can only assume that your assumption / assertion that you are creating new instances each time is in fact incorrect.

Comment: "I can only assume that your assumption / assertion that you are creating new instances each time is in fact incorrect." ? How it is incorrect when I am creating a new instance everytime.

Comment: a new `Resource` is being created every time, however, the underlying `BufferedReader` is clearly the same instance.

Comment: @user882196 - I'm saying that the hashcodes being equals implies that you are NOT creating an instance every time.

Comment: ya thats what I am saying ..whyit is same when i am doing new BufferedReader everytime.

Comment: @user882196 - And I'm saying that it is the same because ... what ever you might think ... you are NOT "doing new BufferedReader everytime".  The code snippets you've pasted into the question don't fit together, and won't compile.  Besides, they appear to show that you can create new Resource objects *without* creating new stream / reader objects.

Comment: @user882196 - you are free to disbelieve me and look for an alternative explanation.  But I don't think you'll find one.