# what happens when you call a synchronized from a non-synchronized method in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My question is about the scanner and BufferedReader class: For example when you do:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("new.txt")));
```

Does this make the scan instance take the advantage of the fact `BufferedReader` is `thread-safe`. would it be thread safe since it's reading from a thread-safe buffer?

I read somewhere that This new scanner would have the bufferedReader's advantage of synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

it looks for me that Java doc doesn't mention that BufferReader is thread safe but from this link [is buffered reader thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342172/is-buffered-reader-thread-safe)
someone reads the source code and it is!

however this doesn't mean Scanner is thread safe. in the java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html, it says

```
A Scanner is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization.
```

Comment: I would just add that `Scanner` is not only operating on it's `Reader` but also does some work of it's own. It has some internal state and that's why you can't assume it will be thread safe when a thread safe `Reader` is used. The same applies to any non thread safe class